# php curl return 400 for existing URL

Tags: php

I create a function to verify if url exist or not, it's working except for some urls like from soundcloud, urls from soundcloud return 400 but the pages exist
I have no space or any special character in the url 
my code is

```
$curl = curl_init($page_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

`var_dump ($result)` //return **true**

`var_dump ($statusCode)` // return **int(400)**

I tried using

```
`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE`
`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE`
```

but is the same result `var_dump ($statusCode)` // return **int(400)**

Answer (score 1):

Technically the status code 400 (Bad Request) doesn’t mean that the page doesn’t exist, It means that the website/API that you’re trying to visit was expecting some input from the user/developer to be in a specific format which the user that’s visiting the website failed to supply.

Since you are trying to CURL a website ( and not an API ) I’d suggest that you open the website with a web browser , and check for any cookies that the website require to function properly and include those cookies in your CURL requests.

**EDIT:**

To Include cookies to your CURL you use the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` CURL Option :

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'user=ellen; activity=swimming');
```

And keep in mind that not all pages are meant to be browsed anonymously, some web pages might require that you log in to view them.

Comment: thanks for the answers, how can I include cookies to my curl

Comment: the page is not accessible for log in , but I tried to add your code but still getting the url not exist

Comment: You're not supposed to use the code that I wrote as it is, Instead, you have to open the page that you're getting the (400) status code from and check what cookies that pages requires and include that cookies -using the option that I mentioned in my updated answer- to include them to mimic a browser, 
you know what I mean ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly how ?